# image from httpresponse to bitmap with Spring

Tags: android, spring, bitmap, jpeg, httprequest

I am trying to do a http request on a url. I thought it would response with an Bitmap in the body of the response, but i get the following error:

```
03-13 22:54:36.106: W/System.err(26547): org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [android.graphics.Bitmap] and content type [image/jpg;charset=utf-8]
03-13 22:54:36.106: W/System.err(26547):    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:79)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:655)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:641)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at com.hera.ooshopping.AsyncPicLoading.getFileFromServer(AsyncPicLoading.java:174)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at com.hera.ooshopping.AsyncPicLoading.doInBackground(AsyncPicLoading.java:65)
03-13 22:54:36.116: W/System.err(26547):    at com.hera.ooshopping.AsyncPicLoading.doInBackground(AsyncPicLoading.java:1)
```

From the error it looks like the response is a JPG (first line), but i am not really sure. I can parse the response to a string, what creates a gigantic string with strange characters, so not base64.

How can i parse my responsebody to an bitmap or image what is useable? I really don't get it. My code with the request is below:

> 

```
HttpBasicAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);

HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
System.out.println("entity:" + requestEntity.toString());

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());

try {
    // GET Request
    ResponseEntity<Bitmap> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Bitmap.class);

    return response.getBody();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over the same problem.

The `ResourceHttpMessageconverter` cannot directly convert the `Resource` to a bitmap. Instead you can use this to create your bitmap:

```
ResponseEntity<Resource> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Resource.class);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getBody().getInputStream());
```

This code works for me. Let me know if that fixes your problem.